# smooth streaming in html5

Tags: html, drm, smooth-streaming, playready

Is there a way to a play video in html5 player using smooth streaming?? I have a requirement of playing Playready Drm protected videos....I tried using the Dash player , using this link
http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/HTML5/eme/ however unlike these videos where a mpd response is available using
url/manifest(format=mpd-time-csf) 
But in my case there is no mpd available only smooth streaming response is available....
Any help please??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this project: https://github.com/Orange-OpenSource/hasplayer.js

It extends dash.js player with support of "vanilla" Smooth Streaming.

I tested it and it works fine with SmoothStreaming/PlayReady test stream:
http://playready.directtaps.net/smoothstreaming/SSWSS720H264PR/SuperSpeedway_720.ism/Manifest

Comment: Safari Yosemite as well

Comment: it works on browsers supporting MSE (Media Source Extensions) and for PlayReady DRM also EME (Encrypted Media Extensions). See
http://caniuse.com/#feat=mediasource